# Why operating systems freeze after wake up?

Tags: linux, windows, freeze, suspend

Operating systems aren't alright with suspending on my computer. Windows can't go suspend and couple of Ubuntu flavors freeze after wake up (both KDE and XFCE) (21.04 and 20.04). Ubuntu's 20.04 never did that before. What should I look at?

Answer (score 1):

Update the Host Machine BIOS and then update the Power Management drivers for both machines.

I suggest resetting Power Settings to default as well.

Properly set up, Windows will suspend just fine. Windows not suspending properly is a driver and settings issue.